# flyway sbt placeholder substitution not working

Tags: flyway

Using Flyway 2.3 on Windows, same result from command prompt and within cygwin. Production env is Linux, but haven't been able to test there yet.

My SQL file has the line:

```
alter table person add ${new_col} text;
```

I added the following to my build.sbt, based on what I saw on the the flyway sbt doc page:

```
flywayPlaceholders := Map(
    "new_col" -> "temp_name"
)
```

When I run

```
> sbt flywayMigrate
```

I get this:

```
com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder expressions: ${new_col}.  Check your configuration!
```

Under cygwin it does work if I specify the substitution on the command line:

```
> sbt flywayMigrate -Dflyway.placeholders.new_col=temp_name
```

Command line plaveholder substitution doesn't work in Windows command prompt, but I suspect that's a different issue as none of my -D options are respected there.

I'm new to both sbt and Flyway, so I'm hoping this is something simple, but I couldn't find anything helpful by googling. thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2):

The flywayPlaceholders in build.sbt are currently by the commandline configuration.
This is a bug in Flyway.
I created a [pull request](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/727).